# Erro sendredirect em Interceptor

Tags: spring-mvc, java

Estou estudado Java Web e preciso fazer uma aplicação com restrição de acesso. Restringindo o acesso caso o usuário não esteja logado (ou seja a sessão criada), caso o usuário acesse alguma URL sem estar logado, deve redirecionar para a tela de *login*. No entanto estou recebendo como resposta do navegador, que muitos redirecionamentos foram feitos.

Alguém saberia me orientar o porque deste erro?

**AutorizacaoInterceptor.java:**

```
public class AutorizacaoInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object controller) throws Exception {
        if(!request.getRequestURI().endsWith("login") && null != request.getSession().getAttribute("userId")){
            return true;
        }

        response.sendRedirect("login");
        return false;
    }

}
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml:**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.infnet" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/"/>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="br.com.infnet.model.AutorizacaoInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

[image: Erro send redirect]

Comment: Por favor não cole sprint screens de código. Poste o código formatado e descrição dos erros ao invés disso.

Answer (score 1):

Você está com um loop infinito de redirecionamentos para a página de login. Pela lógica do seu if no interceptor, você tratou os casos

1. Não é a página de login **e** já está logado
2. Todos os outros casos

Faltou tratar o caso

3. É a página de login e não estou logado (não pode cair no caso 2 acima, senão vai dar loop infinito, que é o que está acontecendo).

Talvez você quisesse usar uma lógica diferente, com o operador **ou** em vez de **e** (ex.: se página de login **ou** já logado), ou pode ser melhor quebrar a lógica em 2 ifs para garantir que você tratará todas as combinações possíveis. Se necessário, desenhe uma tabela no papel com todos os casos :-)

```
            login    outras páginas
logado      ______ | ______
deslogado   ______ | ______
```

Preencha e confira se o código faz o que você deseja.